# PostgreSQL has no service name on CentOS

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL in a pretty standard way on CentOS 5.5:

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.pgrpms.org/reporpms/9.0/pgdg-centos-9.0-2.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql90-server postgresql90-contrib
chkconfig postgresql-90 on
/etc/init.d/postgresql-90 initdb
```

But for some reason I can't use it with the `service` command because it has no name, .e.g if I do `service --status-all` I get back the following:

```
master (pid 3095) is running...
 (pid 3009) is running...
rdisc is stopped
```

Or even just `/etc/init.d/postgresql-90 status`:

```
 (pid 3009) is running...
```

So how can I give it a name so that I don't have to type out the whole init script path each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service name is just the name of the script, i.e, `postgresql-90`.

However, I just installed postgres following your commands above the the init script is actually called `postgresql-9.0`, not `postgresql-90`.

```
$ sudo /sbin/service postgresql-9.0 status
 (pid  16670) is running...
```

I'm sure you're dying to know why it doesn't tell you the name of the service, aren't you? It's because `/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.0` doesn't call the function `status` correctly:

```
status -p /var/run/postmaster-${PGMAJORVERSION}.${PGPORT}.pid
```

From `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`:

```
status() {
        local base pid pid_file=

        # Test syntax.
        if [ "$#" = 0 ] ; then
                echo $"Usage: status [-p pidfile] {program}"
                return 1
        fi
        ...
```

Thus `/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.0` should be

```
status -p /var/run/postmaster-${PGMAJORVERSION}.${PGPORT}.pid $0
```

and the output is correct:

```
$ sudo /sbin/service postgresql-9.0 status
postgresql-9.0 (pid  16670) is running...
```